# Remove about:blank and date-time from pdf in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

```
      const { params } = request.body;
     
      const GENERATE_UUID = uuidv4();

      const path = `generated/letter_list_${GENERATE_UUID}.pdf`;

      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ["--headless"],
      });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setContent(letter_list.parsed_html_string, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle0",
      });
      await page.emulateMediaType("screen");
      await page.pdf({
        displayHeaderFooter: true,
        path: path,
        margin: { top: "180px", bottom: "100px", left: "30px", right: "30px" },
        printBackground: true,
        format: "A4",
      });
      await browser.close();
```

[Pdf Image create using puppeteer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGsj9.png)
[Pdf Image create using puppeteer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frC4W.png)

I'm using puppeteer with fastify. When I generate pdf document it contains the date-time and about:blank on every page as shown in above images. I want to remove both date-time and about:blank from the pdf.

I tried to everything I could find but couldn't resolve the issue. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add your pdf generator code in the question so we may help you.

Comment: @aaqib90 Hi, I've added the code for creation of pdf.

Comment: Please make displayHeaderFooter: false.

Comment: @aaqib90 But I need displayHeaderFooter to be true because I need to show header footer on every page

Comment: await page.addStyleTag({
  content: `
    @page {
      margin: 0;
    }
    .date-time,.pageNumber,.title{
      display: none !important;
    }
  `,
}); This migth help you

Comment: @aaqib90 Thanks for the solution it worked for me. But it worked when I did margin-bottom: 0, for about:blank. If I add margin: 0 it overlaps the header and content below it.

Comment: @aaqib90 Please add your comment to answer so I can accept it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the below

```
   // Add custom CSS to hide the date-time and about:blank elements
    await page.addStyleTag({
      content: `
        @page {
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .date-time,.pageNumber,.title{
          display: none !important;
        }
      `,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { params } = request.body;
     
const GENERATE_UUID = uuidv4();
const headerHtml = () => {
  return `YOUR HEADER HTML`
}

const footerHtml = () => {
  return `YOUR FOOTER HTML`
}

const path = `generated/letter_list_${GENERATE_UUID}.pdf`;

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  args: ["--headless"],
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setContent(letter_list.parsed_html_string, {
  waitUntil: "networkidle0",
});
await page.emulateMediaType("screen");
await page.pdf({
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  headerTemplate: headerHtml(),
  footerTemplate: footerHtml(),
  path: path,
  margin: { top: "180px", bottom: "100px", left: "30px", right: "30px" },
  printBackground: true,
  format: "A4",
});
await browser.close();
```

Updated answer in case if margin is needed